# How to implement sender.selected if statement into UISlider?

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, volume, ibaction

I am trying to create a slider that changes audio dependent on the value of the slider. So, for example, if the slider value is 0, no audio plays. If the value is 1, 'song a' plays and if the value is 2, 'song b' plays etc.

I am using AVFoundation and have created my soundplayer:

```
var soundPlayer:AVAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
```

I have added outlets to my slider:

```
@IBOutlet weak var audioSlider: UISlider!
@IBOutlet weak var audioSliderPlay: UISlider!
```

Defined the file location of my audio:

```
 let audioLocation = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("song a", ofType: ".mp3")
```

Created a do method for my player:

```
do {
audioSoundPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer (contentsOfURL: NSURL (fileURLWithPath: audioLocation!))
catch {
        print(error)
    }
```

And created my action:

```
@IBAction func audioSlider(sender: UISlider) {
    if (!sender.selected) {
        audioSoundPlayer.play()
        audioSoundPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1
    }
```

Now - the slider currently activates song a when *any* value is chosen. Once the audio has started, it cannot be stopped. I need to add a sender.value and create variables that define the value and choose other songs that I am going to add.

Help please?!

**Edit with Amit issue:**

Amit - I have changed the maximum value of the slider to 3 for 3 audios.

On adding the following to the IBAction, the slider only plays one audio once it reaches the maximum value:

```
@IBAction func audioSlider(sender: UISlider) {
    let sliderValue = (sender.value)
    if sliderValue == 1 {
       soundPlayer1.play()
        soundPlayer1.numberOfLoops = -1

    }
    else if sliderValue == 2 {
       soundPlayer2.play()
        soundPlayer2.numberOfLoops = -1


    }
    else if sliderValue == 3 {
        soundPlayer3.play()
        soundPlayer3.numberOfLoops = -1

    }
    else if sliderValue == 0 {
soundPlayer1.stop()
soundPlayer2.stop()
soundPlayer3.stop()
    }
}
```

Comment: if you want the slider value just use "let value = Int(sender.value)"

Comment: sliderValue that you are getting is a Float value which will not match exactly with 1.0 or 2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You slider's `value` property as `sender.value` as typecast it to Int and change the audio according to your need.

You do need to set the `minimum` and `maximum` value of the slider before using it.

Set default to `0`, minimum to `0` and maximum to your need or number of songs you have.

You can use the "pattern-match" operator ~=:

```
let sliderValue = Int(slider.value)

if 100 ... 199 ~= sliderValue {
    print("play audio 1")
}
else if 200 ... 299 ~= sliderValue {
    print("play audio 2")
}
```

Comment: Thanks Amit. I have done this but am having some problems with my if else statement:

 @IBAction func audioSlider(sender: UISlider) {
        let sliderValue = (sender.value)
        if sliderValue == 100-199 {
            soundPlayer1.play()
            soundPlayer1.numberOfLoops = -1

        }
        else if sliderValue == 200-299 {
            soundPlayer2.play()
            soundPlayer2.numberOfLoops = -1


        }
        else if sliderValue == 0-99 {

        }

What am I missing? - the player simply plays one of the sounds. The slider is set at value 300

Comment: Please update your question with your problem. Also if you are playing the same soundPlayer for range 100-199 or so, what is the purpose of taking the range? Please explain your problem in the question itself.

Comment: Also, as per your last comment, seems your condition always taking -99 as 100-199 = -99, 200-299 = -99

Comment: It is possible that the sliderValue may not match as it is a floatValue. You need to typecast it to Int as I've done in my updated answer

Comment: Happy to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

1.Set the Slider's max value as number of audio files present in the bundle.

2.Create an array containing the file name or resource path for all the audio.
 Like

```
slider.maxValue = 5;
let audioPaths = ["1.mp3", "2.mp3", "3.mp3", "4.mp3", "5.mp3"];

@IBAction func audioSlider(sender: UISlider) 
{
     var index = Int(sender.value);
     let audioPath = audioPaths[index];
    do
    {
         audioSoundPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer (contentsOfURL: NSURL (fileURLWithPath: audioLocation!))
         catch 
         {
             print(error)
         } 
    }
}
```